# Propagation speed and capacitors charging speed of transmission line

Tags: electromagnetism, transmission-line, charge, electron, propagation

I am a bit confused on the speed of voltage propagation in the transmission line and I hope someone can enlighten me. I understand the speed of step up voltage propagation is in the same order as the speed of light and it is much faster than current. But if we can model the transmission line with a distributed element model as the image below, how can the modelled capacitors got charged so fast at a rate proportional to the speed of voltage propagation if an electron travel much slower?

[image: voltage propagation]

Source: [All About Circuits - Lessons in Electric Circuits, AC, Transmission Lines, Characteristic Impedance](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/alternating-current/chpt-14/characteristic-impedance/)

Comment: eyew18 - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, the source webpage or PDF etc. should be linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). In order to help you, I found what I believe to be the source webpage link & added it for you. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson It's a perennial problem, noobs not attributing images. Has it ever been suggested to the powers that be that the 'add image' process gets a prompt along the lines of 'have you attributed this content correctly?'

Comment: @Neil_UK when doing that, it should also be enforced that the "add image description" be actually an image description. Not only would that actually help visually impaired readers, I hope it would also eliminate a lot of image spam if people were to actually type down "random image copied from google images for the term in my question title, not actually related to the question". Then again, that hope is probably in vain; "add image description" *should* be clear enough for any sensible question.

Answer (score 0):

The drift velocity of electrons in an electric circuit is indeed slow. However, that doesn't mean that current doesn't "propagate" at very high speeds, often a significant fractions of the speed of light.

To give an analogy, consider a alpine cable car. When the cable pulley is engaged at the top of the mountain, within a very short period the cable all along the way, including the bottom is moving. If the cable system is 1 km and it takes 5 seconds to set the entire cable completely in motion, the "motion" propagates at 720 km/hr. But the cable, and the cars on the cable might be moving at only 2 km/hr.

By analogy, the drift velocity of electrons might be compared to the speed of the cable cars. But the delay between when voltage is applied at one end of a transmission line, and current begins to flow some distance away might be compared to how quickly the cable at the bottom of the mountain begins to move after the pulley at the top is engaged.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I did read about some other analogies similar to yours but I don't understand how they can agree with the distributed element model typically used to explain transmission line such as the one in the image. According to the model, propagation requires capacitor to be charged up one after another along the transmission line. If this is the case, that means electrons need to travelling from the + side to the - side in order to charge a capacitor but if electron is indeed traveling very slowly then how can voltage propagate that fast in the transmission line?

Comment: @eyew18 Electrons do not travel from one side of a capacitor to the other.

Comment: What I meant was electrons move from one plate of the capacitor to the other plate through the voltage source or battery. But it's not important here as long as you agree electrons need to flow from/to voltage source from/to capacitor to charge.